# How to target Sub-Category of Sub-Category

Tags: category, children

I have 2 Main Groups of Categories, which themselves have Sub-Categories.
The Categories you see have checkboxes to filter entries below.
One Sub-Group has also Children (With Material/ Without Material) ->Screenshot.
I need to collapse these two groups (on click they open/close).
**How can i target these Sub-sub-Category Groups?**
Right now i use:

```
{% ifchildren %}
 <ul class="subcategory-list">
   {% children %}
 </ul>
{% endifchildren %}
```

[image]

I tried some with siblings but cannot get it to work. I also need to add extra html fot the arrow to indicate the collapse and to open the sublist.
 If i add it right now, it gets added to all category-groups.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure, but I think you might need to use `level` in your loop.

```
{% set categories = craft.categories.group('groupHandle').level(3) %}

{% for category in categories %}
    // etc
{% endfor %}
```

Have a look at the docs:

https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/craft.categories#level